# Importing servers/server groups using pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have the JSON with the server connection details. I want to import those servers but import/export option under tools menu is disabled for me. Is there a file location where I can place that json file and so that the servers get exported when I start pgAdmin?

I tried to import using the import/export wizard but that is disabled.